# Check for a string value in a table in lua

Tags: string, function, lua, lua-table

I'm trying to create a function where I check for a string value in a table.

If I declare a variable like:

```
local table = "blue"
```

my function:

```
function check(color)
    if color == "blue" then
        return true
    end
return false
end
```

It works without trouble when I use `check(table)` and returns `true`, but when the variable is a table with string values:

```
local table = {"blue", "yellow", "red"}
```

When I try to use the function `check(table)`
Then my function doesn't work, I get the error:

> cannot convert a table to a clr type System.String

Any idea why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: To prevent trouble as you continue to learn the language, you might want to remember that `table` is the name of one of the builtin modules, and is already a global variable containing a table of functions that do interesting things to tables, such as `table.sort()` for sorting. There are several such modules, and it is common practice to avoid reusing those names. As of Lua 5.3 these are `coroutine`, `debug`, `io`, `math`, `os`, `package`, `string`, `table`, and `utf8`.

Comment: @RBerteig Ah yes, I forgot about the predefined words for lua to write this example. Thank you for making me notice it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you have to use == instead of = if you want to check for equality.
Like in many other programming languages = is the assignment operator and == is the logical operator equal
If you want to check if a table contains the string "blue" you have to compare it's elements against "blue", not the table itself!

What you do here is like trying to find out if there are apples or bananas in a bucket. So you check if the bucket looks like a banana.

Try this:

```
function check(colours)
  for i,v in ipairs(colours)

    if v == "blue" then
      return true
    end

  end

end
```

Your code demonstrates quite a lack of knowledge about Lua's basics.
I recommend reading the Lua reference manual and the free eBook Programming in Lua.

http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/

https://www.lua.org/pil/

Comment: I must admit the = was a typo, and yeah, my knowledge about any basic code it's still basic to none (I'm just a fan of coding). Even tho I tried reading the manual it's quite difficult for me to fully understand it, but thanks for your answer. One more question, does that function works with either a table or a single defined variable like my 1st example?

Comment: The code you provided only checks for the first element of the table, and it returns true if it's "blue" or false otherwise. `return false` should be after the loop, not in the else part of the color check.

Comment: @Emuuung no, it doesn't work with both tables and variables, you should use an if-then-else statement that checks if the variable passed is a table or another type of value.

Comment: I would second the advice to read PiL. It is the official introduction to the language. The free version online covers Lua 5.0, but most of the differences are unimportant to a new learner.